# I am trying to install openldap on centos 7 but getting error while checking configurationslaptest -u

Tags: openldap, phpldapadmin

i am trying to run the following command

```
[root@ldap cn=config]# slaptest -u
```

And the following exception is thrown

> 5a716d94 ldif_read_file: checksum error on
>   "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/old1_olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif"
>   database init failed (monitor) 5a716d94 olcDatabase: value #0: only
>   one monitor database allowed (monitor) 5a716d94 config error
>   processing olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config: only one monitor database
>   allowed slaptest: bad configuratshort:e!

in short : it is unable to initualize database with error :

> only one monitor database allowed (monitor) 5a716d94 config error
>   processing olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config: only one monitor database
>   allowed..

thanks in advance for any advice or some light on the issue..

Comment: What part of 'only one monitor database allowed' didn't you understand? Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you edited `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/old1_olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif` by hand and not using `ldapmodify`. So the file checksum (second line in this file) is not correct anymore. If it is a new installation reinstall openldap.